# Hooks in Elastic Beanstalk V3.0.1 (Amazon Linux 2) for configuration updates

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

As described in the AWS docs there are platform hooks for elastic beanstalk EBS for the deployment process: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html

But what can I do, to run a script each time someone changes the EBS configuration, e. g. an environment property?

Comment: Your app is redeployed if env variable changes.

Comment: @Marcin No, it isn't. That was the behavior of Amazon Linux, but it looks like it has been changed for Amazon Linux 2.

Comment: For those who have an AWS account you might have a look at https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=323022&tstart=0

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the current docs here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html, under Platform hooks -> Configuration deployment platform hooks, it explains:

> A configuration deployment occurs when you make configuration changes that only update environment instances without recreating them.

And further:

> To provide hooks that run during a configuration deployment, place them under the .platform/confighooks directory in your source bundle

So adding a Configuration deployment platform hook in this way should execute each time an environment property is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to do this currently:
https://github.com/aws/elastic-beanstalk-roadmap/issues/15#issuecomment-616843537